# Setting form position if user double-clicks to maximise size

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

When the user attempts to maximise the form by double clicking on the top section, I want the form to keep the size - i.e. no maximising and no minimising allowed. I have changed the *StartPosition* to *CenterScreen* (default position is now centre) and inserted code to allow no resizing:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MaximumSize = this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
}
```

This works great! **But** when the user double clicks, the form then defaults to the top left-hand corner - I want it to be centred. I was looking at the different Form1 handlers but I'm not sure which could be of use.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simple... you can try like below. It will help you...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Form Properties to control that. usually you don't need to control everything by code.

in the Form Properties set these fields like below

```
MaximumSize = somesize
MinimumSize = somesize
WindowPosision = center
```